# How do I configure mini-css-extract-plugin in Gatsby?

Tags: webpack, gatsby, mini-css-extract-plugin

### The problem

When I run `npm run build` in my Gatsby project, I'm getting multiple warnings of the same kind:

```
warn chunk styles [mini-css-extract-plugin]
Conflicting order. Following module has been added:
 * css ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--12-oneOf-0-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss-4!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.j
s??ref--12-oneOf-0-3!./src/components/MineralsHeading/MineralsHeading.module.scss
despite it was not able to fulfill desired ordering with these modules:
 * css ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--12-oneOf-0-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss-4!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.j
s??ref--12-oneOf-0-3!./src/components/Carousel/Carousel.module.scss
warn chunk styles [mini-css-extract-plugin]
Conflicting order. Following module has been added:
 * css ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--12-oneOf-0-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss-4!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.j
s??ref--12-oneOf-0-3!./src/components/MineralsSubtitle/MineralsSubtitle.module.scss
despite it was not able to fulfill desired ordering with these modules:
 * css ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--12-oneOf-0-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss-4!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.j
s??ref--12-oneOf-0-3!./src/components/Carousel/Carousel.module.scss
warn chunk styles [mini-css-extract-plugin]
Conflicting order. Following module has been added:
 * css ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--12-oneOf-0-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss-4!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.j
s??ref--12-oneOf-0-3!./src/components/PageSection/PageSection.module.scss
despite it was not able to fulfill desired ordering with these modules:
 * css ./node_modules/css-loader??ref--12-oneOf-0-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss-4!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.j
s??ref--12-oneOf-0-3!./src/components/Carousel/Carousel.module.scss
```

### The cure

I've read [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5372#issuecomment-467824427) and [here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin#remove-order-warnings) that those warnings can be ignored, when using some CSS scoping mechanisms and that's often the only solution to get rid of them.

As I'm using CSS Modules, I decided to pass that `ignoreOrder: true` option to `mini-css-extract-plugin`, like it's described in [it's documentation](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin#remove-order-warnings).

### The question

But I don't know how to do it - customize Webpack configuration for `mini-css-extract-plugin` - in Gatsby, which doesn't have a proper dedicated Webpack configuration file.

[Gatsby's documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/add-custom-webpack-config/) has an article how to customize a Webpack configuration. I read it, but still wasn't able to pass the configuration option to `mini-css-extract-plugin` as I want.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you can see in [Gatsby documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/node-apis/) in your `gatsby-node.js` Gatsby exposes a few APIs to change webpack's default configuration, one of them, `onCreateWebpackConfig`, extends and mutates this configuration allowing you to fit your requirements:

> Let plugins extend/mutate the site’s webpack configuration.
>
> See also the documentation for [`setWebpackConfig`](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/actions/#setWebpackConfig).

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, actions, getConfig }) => {
  if (stage === 'build-javascript') {
    const config = getConfig()
    const miniCssExtractPlugin = config.plugins.find(
      plugin => plugin.constructor.name === 'MiniCssExtractPlugin'
    )
    if (miniCssExtractPlugin) {
      miniCssExtractPlugin.options.ignoreOrder = true
    }
    actions.replaceWebpackConfig(config)
  }
}
```

There's no much mistery, the code is self-explanatory. Basically you look for  `mini-css-extract-plugin` with `plugin.constructor.name === 'MiniCssExtractPlugin'` and set your `ignoreOrder` option as `true`. Afterward, you replace webpack's default stage `action` with `actions.replaceWebpackConfig(config)`.

Because `stage === 'build-javascript'` the snippet only affects in the building stage but you can simply remove it to allow the configuration affects among stages and modes (development and build).

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks.

Comment: But is just switching this off the solution for this problem? I think there is some form of intent behind this. What is the issue here why is this warning popping up??

Edit: I found another entry that suggest the same but explains it better:
https://spectrum.chat/gatsby-js/general/having-issue-related-to-chunk-commons-mini-css-extract-plugin~0ee9c456-a37e-472a-a1a0-cc36f8ae6033

Comment: It's not a "problem" is a webpack warning. In the bundling process, webpack fetches all the needed assets. If you are using plain CSS, the class names are global among files, their order importation matters and can cause some issues in types definitions when they are applied to a certain element (not in the proper styles). If you are using a CSS module each class name is scoped to a file by being prefixed. In that case, the order doesn't matter. Your styles will be applied correctly no matter what since they are transpiled but webpack still bothering about that because of the inherent behavior

Comment: Of course, ideally, the warnings should be fixed but in 90% of the cases, the warnings are applied to third-party dependencies in `node_modules`, not in the project files itself. If you are not using that files, you can ignore them by setting the `ignoreOrder` to  `true` (the case of the question)