# inject style into DOM using link tag in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, gatsby

Is there any way to configure gatsby to inject a style file using a link tag?

currently, I have a global style (style.less) which I import it using a [Layout Component](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/global-css/#adding-global-styles-with-a-layout-component). It's ok but It injects all CSS content into each page and bumps the page size.

I want to configure gatsby to load this style file using a link tag instead of injecting directly into DOM. webpack has an [option](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/style-loader/#linktag) for this purpose but I couldn't find anything similar for Gatsby.

Comment: This might be helpful: [How do I configure MiniCssExtractPlugin in Gatsby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63124432/how-do-i-configure-mini-css-extract-plugin-in-gatsby)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ actions, loaders, getConfig }) => {
  const config = getConfig();

  config.module.rules = [
    ...config.module.rules.filter(rule => String(rule.test) !== String(/\.jsx?$/)),
    {
      test: /\.link\.css$/i,
      use: [
        { loader: `style-loader`, options: { injectType: `linkTag` } },
        { loader: `file-loader` },
      ],
    },
  ];
  actions.replaceWebpackConfig(config);
};
```

Gatsby allows you to customize the webpack's configuration by exposing some APIs (such as [`onCreateWebpackConfig`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/node-apis/#onCreateWebpackConfig) or [`setWebpackConfig`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/actions/#setWebpackConfig)) functions.

The code is quite self-explanatory if you take into account the [`style-loader` from webpack](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/style-loader/#linktag). Basically, you are setting some custom loaders for all files that match the regular expression, and finally, you override the default configuration with `actions.replaceWebpackConfig(config)`.

For further details check [Adding Custom webpack configuration docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/add-custom-webpack-config/).

---

In addition, regarding your original issue, you don't need to add your global styles in your `Layout` component since it will cause what you said, it will bump the page size. With Gatsby, you can use [`gatsby-browser.js` API](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/browser-apis/) to add global styles like (in your `gatsby-browser.js` file):

```
import './src/your/path/to/global/style.less';
```

Check the link you've provided ([Standard Styling with Global CSS file](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/global-css/#adding-global-styles-without-a-layout-component)).