# Ignore order for mini-css-extract-plugin with Gatsby

Tags: webpack, gatsby, css-modules, mini-css-extract-plugin

### Issue:

Console is flooded with warnings like: `warn chunk commons [mini-css-extract-plugin] Conflicting order`. I did some research and found that these warnings can be ignored because I am using css-modules and the order of my imports does not matter. ***Following steps I found to silence the warnings does not work.***

[image: warnings]

### Desired Solution:

Set `ignoreOrder = true` option in the plugin config.

### What I've Tried:

I followed a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63124432/how-do-i-configure-mini-css-extract-plugin-in-gatsby) and added the code to my `gatsby-node.js`:

```js
const path = require('path')

module.exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({
    stage,
    actions,
    getConfig
}) => {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
        resolve: {
            modules: ['node_modules', path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')],
            alias: {
                'basic-info': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app/routes/basic-info'),
                'situation-analysis': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app/routes/situation-analysis'),
                'select-drivers': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app/routes/select-drivers'),
                'define-vision': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app/routes/define-vision'),
                'rate-drivers': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app/routes/rate-drivers'),
                'affinity-groups': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app/routes/affinity-groups'),
                'define-objectives': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app/routes/define-objectives'),
                'create-roadmap': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app/routes/create-roadmap')
            }
        },

        devtool: 'eval-source-map'
    })

    if (stage === 'build-javascript') {
        const config = getConfig()

        const miniCssExtractPlugin = config.plugins.find(
            plugin => (plugin.constructor.name === 'MiniCssExtractPlugin')
        )

        if (miniCssExtractPlugin) miniCssExtractPlugin.options.ignoreOrder = true

        actions.replaceWebpackConfig(config)
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it happen only in `gatsby build` or in `gatsby develop` too?

Comment: This issue persists with both `gatsby build` and `gatsby develop`.

Comment: What version of Gatsby are you running?

Comment: I just migrated from latest v2 to latest v3 (3.4.0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({
    stage,
    actions,
    getConfig
}) => {
    actions.setWebpackConfig({
        resolve: {
            modules: ['node_modules', path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')],
            alias: {
                'basic-info': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app/routes/basic-info'),
                'situation-analysis': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app/routes/situation-analysis'),
                'select-drivers': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app/routes/select-drivers'),
                'define-vision': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app/routes/define-vision'),
                'rate-drivers': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app/routes/rate-drivers'),
                'affinity-groups': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app/routes/affinity-groups'),
                'define-objectives': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app/routes/define-objectives'),
                'create-roadmap': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/app/routes/create-roadmap')
            }
        },

        devtool: 'eval-source-map'
    })

    if (stage === 'build-javascript' || stage === 'develop') {
        const config = getConfig()

        const miniCssExtractPlugin = config.plugins.find(
            plugin => (plugin.constructor.name === 'MiniCssExtractPlugin')
        )

        if (miniCssExtractPlugin) miniCssExtractPlugin.options.ignoreOrder = true

        actions.replaceWebpackConfig(config)
    }
}
```