# I am migrating my Gatsby site from v2 to v3 and I have updated my npm packages but I am getting errors

Tags: reactjs, webpack, gatsby, loader, webpack-5

I am migrating from gatsby v2 to v3 so that I can use Gatsby Incremental build in my website without using Gatsby cloud services but on updating gatsby version and updating every outdated npm packages I am getting errors for this Mini Extract css,

I am having webpack version 5 and node version above 12 and after updating every oudated npm I am not able to solve this mini css extract issue

I am getting this error while running locally :

```
Module build failed (from 
./node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ValidationError: Invalid options object. Mini CSS Extract Plugin Loader has been initialized using  
an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'hmr'. These properties are valid:
   object { publicPath?, emit?, esModule?, layer?, modules? }
    at validate
```

I have setup a webpack.config.js file and here is code of this file can anyone suggest what I am missing that I am getting this hmr error:

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require("css-minimizer-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: "[name].css",
      chunkFilename: "[id].css",
    }),
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      // For webpack@5 you can use the `...` syntax to extend existing minimizers (i.e. `terser-webpack-plugin`), uncomment the next line
      // `...`,
      new CssMinimizerPlugin(),
    ],
    minimize: true,
  },
};
```

Comment: How are you using CSS modules? Can you share the snippet? What is "I've tried everything"?

Comment: @FerranBuireu II have added screenshot of importing css file

Comment: @FerranBuireu  I am getting one error regarding mini-css-extract-plugin where it says hmr is invalid

Comment: Where? When? If you have applied the way I suggest you import the CSS modules please comment on the answer itself below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS modules in Gatsby v3 onwards needs to be imported as ES modules, so your:

```
import styles from './related-products.modules.css'
```

Should be:

```
import * as styles from './related-products.modules.css'
```

Keep in mind that this is not the recommended way of importing CSS modules, since you are not allowing webpack to treeshake your styles. Ideally, you should import the needed named modules like:

```
import { style1, style2, style3 } from './related-products.modules.css'
```

Regarding the new issue:

> I am getting this error while running locally :      `Module build failed (from ./node_modules/gatsby/node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js): ValidationError: Invalid options object. Mini CSS Extract Plugin Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.`

Try adding the (dev)dependencies:

```
yarn add --dev css-loader@^5.0.0 postcss@^8.1.10 postcss-import@^13.0.0 postcss-loader@^4.1.0 postcss-url@^10.1.1
```

Or the equivalence in npm.

Comment: Hey It's still giving same error even after installing the above packages with the version you have mentioned. I have a doubt that how does these packages help me with Mini CSS Extract Plugin Loader that is causing the problem here??

Comment: My guess was that webpack wasn't taking the proper dependencies. Have you used the import as I suggested? `import * as styles from './related-products.modules.css'`? Have you upgraded all the related packages to the latest version?

Comment: Yes I have updated all the css modules in the way you have suggested:                            **import {styles} from './related-products.module.css';** and also have updated to latest packages

Comment: No, it should be `import * as styles from './related-products.modules.css'` the key part is `* as styles`

Comment: after importing css files like **import * as styles from './related-products.modules.css'**  now I am getting these warnings: **warn undefined                                                                                      
chunk commons [mini-css-extract-plugin]                                                             
Conflicting order. Following module has been added:
   - couldn't fulfill desired order of chunk group(s) RelatedProducts-index   and nothing is loading on localhost

Comment: This is a warning, it won't break your compilation and is a signal of your issue resolution. This is happening because of the CSS webpack's order, it's a minor "warning". Follow this answer to get rid of the warning if you want: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63124432/how-do-i-configure-mini-css-extract-plugin-in-gatsby . If the issue has been solved please consider accepting/upvoting the answer to close the issue